# SQL selecting a row that has a newer date than another entry for a FK

Tags: sql, date, if-statement, mariadb, range

I have an SQL question to ask relating to Maria DB 10.4.24.

I have a table that relates to the type/version of first aid certificate that a volunteer holds.  Some versions of this certificate are a newer version than previous types issued in the past.

The versions don't matter, as long as at least one first aid certificate is renewed each year.

Some volunteer's have both certificates as they have moved on and completed the new one (version2), leaving the old one abandoned (version one) but this still remains on their record in the table....or some volunteers will either have the old or the new one, as new volunteer's will start off with version 2, or older volunteer's will have the old version 1 cert that they will keep renewing......they are lazy....

Problem is I need a way of knowing for those who do have both, what the name is of the most recently renewed one, either version one or two,

For those who only have one version of certificate, i still need to know the version.

Table name is: volunteer_awards
columns are:  volunteer_id,award_name,award_expiry_date,

And I'm selecting all three of these columns in the query, but only want to see a row returned for the most recent first aid cert that they have, as I don't need both awards returned, just the most recently renewed,   the date and the name of the cert,    ....and the member ID aswell.

The other issue is that there are other types of awards other than first aid in this table, so one person may have 5 entries in this table of various awards, i'm only focused on the first aid awards version 1 or 2,  and out of those (if there are two) the one with the latest expiry date.

so - I was using something like

```
SELECT volunteer_id, award_name, MAX(award_expiry_date)
FROM volunteer_awards
WHERE volunteer_awards.award_name= "first aid ver1"
OR volunteer_awards.award_name= "first aid ver2"
AND volunteer_id = "123456789";
```

I was curious if this kind of a query would require perhaps an IF statement or MAX(Date) regarding the date?

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your idea should work, but you will see both the max's for the certificates (if they have two). Once you know what is the max date you can wash that back through with a new join to get just the relevant rows.

Let's see how it works.

(NOTE -- in these examples I have written and tested all of this in SQL Server. Some minor adjustments may be needed for other RDBMS's, but most of it is standard sql syntax that works on most platforms).

##### A) create some test data :)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #volunteer_awards;
CREATE TABLE #volunteer_awards (volunteer_id INT, award_name NVARCHAR(30), award_expiry_date DATE);
INSERT INTO #volunteer_awards
VALUES
    (1, 'first aid ver1', '20220131'), -- expected
    (2, 'first aid ver2', '20220131'), -- expected
    (3, 'first aid ver1', '20220131'),
    (3, 'first aid ver1', '20220228'), -- expected
    (4, 'first aid ver1', '20220131'),
    (4, 'first aid ver1', '20220228'),
    (4, 'first aid ver2', '20220228'),
    (4, 'first aid ver1', '20220331'),
    (4, 'first aid ver2', '20220331'), -- expected
    (4, 'other         ', '20221231');
```

##### B) get the volunteers ids with their most recent certificate date

```
SELECT 
    volunteer_id, 
    MAX(award_expiry_date) AS MaxOfAwardExpiryDate
FROM #volunteer_awards
WHERE 
    award_name= 'first aid ver1'
    OR award_name= 'first aid ver2'
GROUP BY volunteer_id
```

| volunteer_id | MaxOfAwardExpiryDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2 | 2022-01-31 |
| 3 | 2022-02-28 |
| 4 | 2022-03-31 |

##### C) use this data to match back to the certificate(s) that were issued on that date

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM
(
    -- Just the volunteer id with their max certificate date
    SELECT 
        volunteer_id, 
        MAX(award_expiry_date) AS MaxOfAwardExpiryDate
    FROM #volunteer_awards
    WHERE 
        award_name= 'first aid ver1'
        OR award_name= 'first aid ver2'
    GROUP BY volunteer_id
) T1
INNER JOIN #volunteer_awards T2
ON T1.volunteer_id = T2.volunteer_id
AND T1.MaxOfAwardExpiryDate = T2.award_expiry_date
```

| volunteer_id | award_name | MaxOfAwardExpiryDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first aid ver1 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2 | first aid ver2 | 2022-01-31 |
| 3 | first aid ver1 | 2022-02-28 |
| 4 | first aid ver1 | 2022-03-31 |
| 4 | first aid ver2 | 2022-03-31 |

##### Final tweak: get only the most recent certificate if two exists for the same expiry date

We do have two rows for volunteer #4 -- that person has two certificates that both expire on the same day and are both the most recent. We can use the fact that `first aid ver2` is "greater than" `first aid ver1` and just go for the max again ... (however, in more complex situations we would likely use a lookup table to join to that would tell us which award is the most recent version).

```
SELECT T1.volunteer_id, MAX(award_name) AS award_name, T2.award_expiry_date
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        volunteer_id, 
        MAX(award_expiry_date) AS MaxOfAwardExpiryDate
    FROM #volunteer_awards
    WHERE 
        award_name= 'first aid ver1'
        OR award_name= 'first aid ver2'
    GROUP BY volunteer_id
) T1
INNER JOIN #volunteer_awards T2
ON T1.volunteer_id = T2.volunteer_id
AND T1.MaxOfAwardExpiryDate = T2.award_expiry_date
GROUP BY T1.volunteer_id, T2.award_expiry_date
```

| volunteer_id | award_name | award_expiry_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first aid ver1 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2 | first aid ver2 | 2022-01-31 |
| 3 | first aid ver1 | 2022-02-28 |
| 4 | first aid ver2 | 2022-03-31 |

##### Another solution using windows functions

Most modern RDBMS's now support [window functions](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/) such as `row_number()`. With these queries, we can partition, sort and number our data - in this case by volunteers and sorting on the certs and their expiration dates. The previous examples use set-based logic and simple queries - which is useful to work through, just to get used to this way of "thinking in SQL" (my opinion, anyway). But nowadays we can write more elegant and powerful SQL to get the same results, so here's an example. I would encourage spending lots of time learning about and trying SQL window functions to get the hang them - they are a great addition to anyone's SQL skillset.

```
SELECT 
    T1.volunteer_id, 
    T1.award_name, 
    T1.award_expiry_date
FROM
(
    
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY volunteer_id 
            ORDER BY award_expiry_date desc, award_name DESC) AS seq,
        *
        FROM #volunteer_awards
        WHERE 
            award_name= 'first aid ver1'
            OR award_name= 'first aid ver2'
) T1
WHERE T1.seq =  1;
```

| volunteer_id | award_name | award_expiry_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first aid ver1 | 2022-01-31 |
| 2 | first aid ver2 | 2022-01-31 |
| 3 | first aid ver1 | 2022-02-28 |
| 4 | first aid ver2 | 2022-03-31 |

This query and the previous one achieve the same results.

Comment: Hi Topsail, I was going to say i think i almost answered my own question by mistake...I have tried my original code and it works.....but thankyou for your reply, However your point that you raised is valid, would there be a way to preference the newer certificate if both had both the same expiry date?

Comment: Great. Yes, this query gives no preference (if it is possible for two types of certificates to be renewed with the same expiration date - then you would need to do a little more work. Is this in the realm of possibility?

Comment: Not 100% sure if it is a possibility but I figured it would be worth safe guarding against human error from someone updating both certificates by accident in the system.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a long-winded set of examples and (possibly) a new solution you will like better.